# android xml Layout issue

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout, inflate

I already spent hours on this, its a layout issue. can someone tell me how to show both image and view switcher in the same activity.

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/rg.client.muscle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fil_parent">
    <ViewSwitcher 
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- contains two relative layouts of same sizes 
        containing same elements just with switched positions -->

        <RelativeLayout 

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
                android:id="@+id/adv" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
                myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
                myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
                myapp:refreshInterval="30" >
            </com.admob.android.ads.AdView>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linear" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:weightSum="100" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_above="@id/adv" >

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_prev2" 
                    android:text="Previous" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="30" >
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_more2" 
                    android:text="More" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="40" >
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_next2" 
                    android:text="Next" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="30">
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linear2" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"  
                android:weightSum="100" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_prev" 
                    android:text="Previous" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="30">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_more" 
                    android:text="More" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="40">
                </Button>

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/but_next" 
                    android:text="Next" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"   
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="30">
                </Button>

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
                android:id="@+id/adv2" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/linear2" 
                myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
                myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
                myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
                myapp:refreshInterval="30">
            </com.admob.android.ads.AdView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_above="@id/relative"
        android:padding="2pt" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I put the imageview first then each time a new image is loaded the buttons disappear and the whole layout seems to be re inflated

Update:

The layout must have an image view at the top then a view switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine a lot of it has to do with you not being able to read your XML. If it looks anything like the way you originally pasted it in here, that is. Your first problem is that you have nothing in your root RelativeLayout tag specifying a size. Your root layout should be in most cases set to a `layout_width` of `fill_parent`, same with the `layout_height`. You also need your schema specification (i.e. `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` although I'm assuming you just left that out, since you're actually getting it to compile.

You also may want to keep in mind, since most everything is set to `wrap_content` for height, if it ever exceeds the height of the screen, some of it will not be visible, so you may consider wrapping the inner portion into a `ScrollView`.

EDIT: Again, I'd suggest setting your RelativeLayout (root element) to have a height of `fill_parent`. Try defining your ImageView first, leaving it with `alignParentTop="true"`, then define your ViewSwitcher, and give it the `layout_below="@id/image"` attribute.

Comment: I am sorry, I just didnt add the things you are saying in here. But they are all setup in the code.

Comment: You should probably add them then, if you want an accurate answer. Try adding `android:layout_below="@id/image"` to your ViewSwitcher. Without knowing your layout, and the content within, it's hard to say. Also, RelativeLayouts don't have an `android:orientation` attribute, just LinearLayout. Using those has no effect on a RelativeLayout.

Comment: fixed it and Also added the part where the image must be.

Comment: Did you try my layout_below suggestion? I've updated my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yes I have tried your suggestion. It does this. Image is shown on the whole screen and after a while buttons appear at the bottom. Every time I get an image from the internet this thing happens.

Comment: For now I have set the height of viewswitcher to 32pt but you know that this isnt a good solution. It can conflict with small screens.

Comment: I am trying to reset the size as soon as I receive the ad, using relativelayout.layoutParams(). Do you think there can be a better way?

Comment: Also when I manually set this It gives the same problem Image View is dragged out of the screen.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually set the size for the ad, wrap_content will handle that. I'm not really sure what the problem is, it could be something related to ViewSwitcher, which I've never used.

Comment: All that is happening is whenever I set the size of view switcher to wrapcontent It takes the whole screen and my views are at the bottom. If I set the size to xxpt the viewswitcher is placed the same place but dosent takes the whole place and ImageView can reside.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. You've got layout_alignParentBottom/Top for views whose parents have wrap_content. You can only use those attributes when the size is fixed or fill_parent. Try removing the alignParentBottom/Top attributes from everything but the ViewSwitcher and the ImageView.

Comment: I will try this soon. Either way I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

And small advice, use include layout, it will be more clear.

```
 <include layout="@layout/my_other_layout" />
```

Comment: I want to follow that, For now I am having trouble dealing with events and all. If I put in the same layouts using include how can I get the id of the buttons.